# Can you map distance bands?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, buffer

I know you can calculate using distance bands, but can you actually illustrate them on the map in ArcGIS? I have a presentation next week, and it would be a useful illustration for me to use.

Comment: are you looking for drive-time polygons or just simple buffers?

Comment: For now just simple buffers. I have not figured out drive-time analysis on Arc yet. Are drive time polygons possible?

Comment: Indeed they are, you would need the Network Analyst extension

Comment: What you are looking for is Service Areas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you use the [Multiple Ring Buffer](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001p000000) tool (ArcToolbox > Analysis Tools > Proximity)

Then input your starting location (1) and the intervals for the buffers (2) the output will be a feature class with 'rings' that you can then symbolise and display to illustrate distance for your presentation.

[image: Multiple ring buffer tool]